# How to create stream using pyspark and kafka an read it row by row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to use pyspark to read a kafka stream and then in further stages I will process each row and store it in influxdb. The problem is pyspark is not reading the stream, no errors are shown.
It's not printing anything but in my code the foreach(show_data) is supposed to print 'test' for each row.

An example row of the stream sent by kafka is attached in the second picture

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName("Kafka Pyspark Streaming")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
)
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('ERROR')


# Read stream from json and fit schema
inputStream = spark\
    .readStream\
    .format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "SWAT")\
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")\
    .load()

inputStream = inputStream.select(col("value").cast("string").alias("data"))
# inputStream.printSchema()

#inputStream =  inputStream.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
print(inputStream)
# Read stream and process

def show_data(row):
    print(f"test")

print(f"> Reading the stream and storing ...")
query = (inputStream
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .foreach(show_data)
    .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoints")
    .start())
    
query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Try calling this method after start() - `awaitTermination()`

Comment: I'm calling query.awaitTermination() in a different line, would it make a difference ?

Comment: That should be okay

Comment: Please show your code as text, not images. Why not use Kafka Connect if you just want to write to Influx?

Comment: It's an academic project and using pyspark is a must, I'll try to add the text for the code