# write pyspark dataframe to kafka - Topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I use the following line to submit the pyspark application, my spark version is 3.0.0:

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0 pyspark_streaming.py'
```

I run both pyspark and kafka inside docker containers, when trying to send pyspark dataframe to kafka

```
df_final.select(to_json(struct([col(c).alias(c) for c in df_final.columns])).alias("value"))\
.writeStream.format("kafka").outputMode("append").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
.option("topic", "test") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoints").start().awaitTermination()
```

I got the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Comment: What happens when you search the web for "TimeoutException: Topic test not present in metadata after 60000 ms"? Do you find anything that helps you? If not, what *do* you find and why does it not resolve your issue? By including that info in an [edit] you prevent that people will suggest something that you've tried already and which didn't work.

Comment: I posted here because could not find anything that help, the edit was just because I put a wrong code

Comment: All solutions for that error are either 1) That topic does not exist as the error says 2) Your Kafka cluster requires authentication/authorization, and you didn't provide any settings to do so, therefore topic names cannot be looked up. So, therefore, please prove to us the topic does exist with `kafka-topics --describe` output... Also, select code could probably be simplified to something like `selectExpr("to_json(struct('*'))").alias('value').`

Comment: @LA. "*could not find anything that help*", that's fine as well, but then please [edit] your question and include what you've searched for when you could not find anything helpful.

Comment: the topic is created, so the problem is in the connection itself, another question that I asked earlier was concerning the problem from writing stream from kafka to spark and then printing it, it does not work either [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74533601/how-to-create-stream-using-pyspark-and-kafka-an-read-it-row-by-row)